# How to derive the type for Haskell record fields?

Tags: haskell, monads

Coming from OOP this seems like alien code to me.

I don't understand why type of `runIdentity` is a function :

`runIdentity :: Identity a -> a` ? I specified to be `runIdentity :: a`

```
newtype Identity a = Identity {runIdentity :: a} deriving Show

instance Monad Identity where
  return = Identity
  Identity x >>= k = k x

instance Functor Identity where
  fmap  f (Identity x) = Identity (f x)

instance Applicative Identity where
  pure = Identity
  Identity f <*> Identity v = Identity (f v)

wrapNsucc :: Integer -> Identity Integer
wrapNsucc = Identity . succ
```

Calling `runIdentity` :

> runIdentity $ wrapNsucc 5 -- gives 6 as output

Comment: Are you familiar with any OOP languages at all? `class C {int x;}; C i;` now `i.x` is an `int`, likewise if you have `i :: Identity Int` then `runIdentity i` is an `Int`. So if `i` is an `Identity Int` and `runIdentity i` is an `Int` then what is `runIdentity`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're right that `runIdentity` is but a simple field of type `a`. But the *type* of `runIdentity` is `Identity a -> a`, since `runIdentity` is a function to extract that field out of a `Identity a`. You can't get the `runIdentity` out of a value without supplying which value to get it from, after all.

Edit:
To expand a little on that OOP-analogy in the comments, think of a class

```cs
class Identity<T> {
    public T runIdentity;
}
```

This is the `Identity` monad, loosely translated to OOP code. The template argument `T` basically is your `a`; as such, `runIdentity` is of type `T`. To get that `T` from your object, you'd probably do something like

```cs
Identity<int> foo = new Identity<int>();
int x = foo.runIdentity;
```

You see `runIdentity` as something of type `T`, but it's not really. You can't just do

```cs
int x = runIdentity; // Nope!
```

because - where to get the `runIdentity` from? Instead, think of this like doing

```cs
Identity<int> foo = new Identity<int>();
int x = runIdentity(foo);
```

This shows what actually happens when you're calling a member; you have a function (your `runIdentity`) and supply it an object to use - IIRC this is what Python does with `def func(self)`. So instead of being plainly of type `T`, `runIdentity` is actually taking an `Identity<T>` as argument to return a `T`.

Thus, it's of type `Identity a -> a`.

Comment: But if I wanted `runIdentity` to be a function shouldn't I write `newtype Identity a =  Identity {runIdentity :: Identity a -> a}` ?

Comment: If you'd write it like that, the type of ```runIdentity``` would be ```Identity a -> Identity a -> a```. Since you're coming from OOP, think of it like this: You call a member function ```foo.bar()```, which returns something of type ```a```. You'd think the function ```bar()``` has type ```a```, but that wouldn't be a function now, would it? Instead, it uses the ```foo``` (which - for convenience - is of type ```Identity a```) to return that ```a```. Written in C for example, that'd be ```a bar(Identity foo)```, which clearly takes a parameter of type ```Identity```: the object itself.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to see this is that record syntax in Haskell is basically just syntactic sugar over algebraic datatypes, i.e. records don't truly exist in Haskell, only algebraic datatypes do, with perhaps some additional syntactic niceties. Hence there isn't a notion of members the same way that classes have in a lot of OO languages.

```
data MyRecord = MyRecord { myInt :: Int, myString :: String }
```

really is just

```
data MyRecord Int String
```

with the additional functions

```
myInt :: MyRecord -> Int
myInt (MyRecord x _) = x

myString :: MyRecord -> String
myString (MyRecord _ y) = y
```

automatically defined.

The only things that you could not do by yourself with normal algebraic datatypes that record syntax gives you are a nice way of making a copy of `MyRecord` that only has a subset of fields changed and a nice way of naming certain patterns.

```
copyWithNewInt :: Int -> MyRecord -> MyRecord
copyWithNewInt x r = r { myInt = x }

-- Same thing as myInt, just written differently
extractInt :: MyRecord -> Int
extractInt (MyRecord { myInt = x }) = x
```

Because this is just syntactic sugar over ordinary algebraic datatypes, you could always fall back to doing things the usual way.

```
-- This is a more verbose but also valid way of doing things
copyWithNewInt :: Int -> MyRecord -> MyRecord
copyWithNewInt x (MyRecord _ oldString) = MyRecord x oldString
```

Incidentally this is why some otherwise ridiculous-seeming constraints exist (the most prominent is that you can't have another type defined with record syntax with `myInt` again, otherwise you're creating two functions in the same scope with the same name, which Haskell does not allow).

Therefore

```
newtype Identity a = Identity {runIdentity :: a} deriving Show
```

is equivalent (minus convenient update syntax which doesn't really matter when you have only one field) to

```
newtype Identity a = Identity a deriving Show

runIdentity :: Identity a -> a
runIdentity (Identity x) = x
```

Using record syntax just compresses all that into a single line (and perhaps gives more insight into why `runIdentity` is named that, i.e. as a verb, rather than as a noun).

Answer (score 3):

```
newtype Identity a = Identity {runIdentity :: a} deriving Show
```

Using the record syntax here, you're really creating two things called `runIdentity`.

One is the field of the constructor `Identity`. You can use that with record pattern syntax, as in `case i of Identity { x = runIdentity } -> x`, where matching a value `i :: Identity a` to extract the field's contents into a local variable `x`. You can also use record construction or update syntax, as in `Identity { runIdentity = "foo" }` or `i { runIdentity = "bar" }`.

In all of those cases `runIdentity` isn't really a standalone thing in its own right. You're using it only as part of a larger syntactic construct, to say which field of `Identity` you're accessing. The "slot" of `Identify a` referred to with the help of the field `runIdentity` does indeed store things of type `a`. But this `runIdentity` field is **not** a value of type `a`. It's not even a value at all really, since it needs to have these extra properties (that values do not have) about referring to a particular "slot" in a data type. Values are standalone things, that exist and make sense on their own. Fields are not; field **contents** are, which is why we use types to classify fields, but fields themselves are not values.<sup>1</sup> Values can be placed in data structures, returned from functions, etc. There's no way to define a value that you can place in a data structure, get back out, and then use with record pattern, construction, or update syntax.

The other thing named `runIdentity` defined with the record match syntax is an ordinary function. Functions *are* values; you can pass them to other functions, put them in data structures, etc. The intent is to give you a helper for getting the value of a field in a value of type `Identity a`. But because you have to specify **which** `Identity a` value you want to get the value of the `runIdentity` field from, you have to pass an `Identity a` into the function. So the `runIdentity` *function* is a value of type `Identity a -> a`, as distinct from the `runIdentity` *field* which is a non-value described by type `a`.

A simple way to see this distinction is to add a definition like `myRunIdentity = runIdentity` to your file. That definition declares that `myRunIdentity` is equal to `runIdentity`, but you can only define *values* like that. And sure enough `myRunIdentity` will be a function of type `Identity a -> a`, that you can apply to things of type `Identity a` to get an `a` value. But it won't be usable with record syntax as the field. The field `runIdentity` didn't "come along with" the value `runIdentity` in that definition.

This question might have been prompted by type `:t runIdentity` into ghci, asking it to show you the type. It would have answered `runIdentity :: Identity a -> a`. The reason is because the `:t` syntax works on **values**<sup>2</sup>. You can type any expression at all there, and it will give you the type of the value that would result. So `:t runIdentity` is seeing the `runIdentity` *value* (the function), not the `runIdentity` field.

As a final note, I've been banging on about how the field `runIdentity :: a` and the function `runIdentity :: Identity -> a` are two separate things. I did so because I thought cleanly separating the two would help people confused by why there can be two different answers to "what is the type of `runIdentity`". But it's also a perfectly valid interpretation to say that `runIdentity` is a single thing, and it's simply the case that when you use a field as a first-class value it behaves as a function. And that is how people often talk about fields. So please don't be confused if other sources insist that there is only one thing; these are simply two different ways of looking at the same language concepts.

---

<sup>1</sup> A perspective on lenses, if you've heard of them, is that they are ordinary values that can be used to give us all of the semantics we need from "fields", without any special-purpose syntax. So a hypothetical language could theoretically not provide any syntax for field access at all, just giving us lenses when we declare a new data type, and we'd be able to make do.

But Haskell record syntax fields aren't lenses; used as values they're only "getter" functions, which is why there's dedicated pattern match, construction, and update syntax for using the fields in ways beyond what is possible with ordinary values.

<sup>2</sup> Well, more properly it works on expressions, since it's type-checking the code, not running the code and then looking at the value to see what type it is (that wouldn't work anyway, since runtime Haskell values don't have any type information in the GHC system). But you can blur the lines and call values and expressions the same kind of thing; fields are quite different.